# How to link customized navigation bar to navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I created a normal view controller with a customized navigation bar. Later I changed my mind to embed the view controller into a navigation controller. And I noticed that embedding the view controller into a navigation controller will create another navigation bar!

As the image show:
[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to replace the navigation bar created by navigation controller with my own customized bar?
Or, if it's not possible, is there a way to configure the new navigation bar? Because for some reason it's not shown in my interface builder.

Comment: Did you mean you created subclass of UINavigationBar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions

1. Hide the system navigationbar using below code so it was display your custom navigation.

   self.navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
2. Customize the system navigation bar with its background color, back button and title text color. For this you can refer a below links which provide you detail of its 
   http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color and buttons of the `UINavigationBar` provided by the system and make it look like yours.